# Quelle serait la formulation la plus idiomatique « Prendre la route pour/vers/en direction de Paris »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Ce soir, je vais prendre la route pour Paris.

> Ce soir, je vais prendre la route vers Paris.

> Ce soir, je vais prendre la route en direction de Paris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**pour Paris** est la seule phrase qui indique qu'on compte aller jusqu'à Paris.
*Vers Paris* ou *en direction de Paris* se valent:
Ce sont des indications de direction, pas de destination.